# React Player does not load video with url in mobile version on chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-player

the attach video link with react player is working smoothly on browser. But when i try to test with mobile versions on chrome it does not load video.

```
   const streamUrl='https://d3nzuksi34yzii.cloudfront.net/4611/240/240p.m3u8';


<ReactPlayer
                ref={playerRef}
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                url={streamUrl}
                pip={pip}
                playing={playing}
                controls={false}
                light={light}
                loop={loop}
                playbackRate={playbackRate}
                volume={volume}
                muted={muted}
                onProgress={handleProgress}
                config={{
                  file: {
                    attributes: {
                      crossorigin: 'anonymous',
                      controlsList: 'nodownload' 
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off the data-saver in Chrome if you are using an Android device.

Comment: I am not using any mobile devices, just testing through mobile versions on chrome